# Unable to cancel a dataflow on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a number of google cloud dataflows marked as "Running"  in the Dataflow console, but there are no GCE instances running.  I manually terminated the instances to avoid being billed.   The dataflows seem to be permanently stuck in "running" state.  If I try to cancel them from the console or gcloud utility, I receive a warning that the flow is already in "finishing state" so the request was ignored.

I am now at the running quota of 10, so I am stuck.  Is there any solution to this other than creating a new project?

Comment: Just noting that we resolved this over email.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue in the Dataflow service that caused cancel requests to become stuck.  It has since been resolved.